# Bind a WPF's control to an F# Option

Tags: wpf, data-binding, f#

Suppose I have a business object (without an `AllowNullLiteralAttribute`).

```
type Person(name: string) =
    member val Name = name
    override x.ToString() = name
```

And a view model, with the selected person optionally set.

```
type MainWindowModel() =

    let mutable selectedPerson: Person option = None
        :
    member val People = ObservableCollection<Person>()
    member x.SelectedPerson
        with get() = selectedPerson
        and set(v) =
            if selectedPerson <> v then
                selectedPerson <- v
                x.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPerson")
```

What is the best way to bind a WPF control's `SelectedItem` property to an F# option property (without using `AllowNullLiteralAttribute`)?

If I do this...

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPerson}" />
</StackPanel>
```

...it results in an error, *Cannot convert 'George' from type 'Person' to type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[Person]'*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The approach I am currently taking is to write my own `IValueConverter`.

```
open System
open System.Globalization
open System.Windows.Data

type OptionsTypeConverter() =

    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289761
    let (|SomeObj|_|) =
      let ty = typedefof<option<_>>
      fun (a:obj) ->
        let aty = a.GetType()
        let v = aty.GetProperty("Value")
        if aty.IsGenericType && aty.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = ty then
          if a = null then None
          else Some(v.GetValue(a, [| |]))
        else None

    interface IValueConverter with

        member x.Convert(value: obj, targetType: Type, parameter: obj, culture: CultureInfo) =
            match value with
            | null -> null
            | SomeObj(v) -> v
            | _ -> value

        member x.ConvertBack(value: obj, targetType: Type, parameter: obj, culture: CultureInfo) =
            match value with
            | null -> None :> obj
            | x -> Activator.CreateInstance(targetType, [| x |])
```

And then my XAML looks like this:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Converter={StaticResource OptionsTypeConverter1}}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPerson, Converter={StaticResource OptionsTypeConverter1}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

There may be a simpler way. This converter may already exist in the framework. There may be better implementations out there.

Comment: `OptionsTypeConverter` only extracts value from option, right? Then how does it convert extracted value to string _and back_ in `TextBlock` or `TextBox`?

Comment: @Lightman OptionsTypeConverter implements `IValueConverter` which has both `Convert(...)` and `ConvertBack(...)` methods. The `Convert(...)` method returns the Option's Value (or null) and the `ConvertBack(...)` method creates a new Option using `Activator.CreateInstance(...)`.

Comment: Yes, it converts option to value and back. But when binding to `Text` property, value (`Person`) has to be converted to string and in case of `TextBox` converted back from string to value. How is it done?

Comment: @Lightman My example is with a `TextBlock`, not a `TextBox`. The `TextBlock` is read-only. In this case, the `override x.ToString() = name` is used by the framework to display the Person. If you really had a `TextBox` with TwoWay binding, you could use a converter that did both the Option conversion and the lookup for a matching Person in the People collection.

Answer (score 3):

I think using an `IValueConverter` is probably the cleanest approach.

Alternatively, you could use the fact that option type has `Value` member (which returns the value for `Some` or throws an exception for `None`). So, if you know that there is always a value, or if the exception does not break anything (I have not tried), you might be able to write:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson.Value}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

If the exception is a problem, then [this past SO question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259315/use-a-default-value-when-binding-cannot-be-evaluated-because-of-a-null-value) to use `PriorityBinding`:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
  <ListBox.SelectedItem>
    <PriorityBinding>
        <Binding Path="SelectedPerson.Value" />
        <Binding Source="{x:Null}" />  <!-- or some other default... -->
    </PriorityBinding>
  </ListBox.SelectedItem>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I find that `.Value` is read only. So the `ListBox` cannot set its value when the user makes a selection. Thanks for the idea, though!